# Poor remote connection performance using Remmina with lowest quality settings

Tags: ubuntu, networking, pop-os, remmina

I'm using `Pop!_OS 20.04 LTS` with `GNOME 3.36.8` and want to use a .rdp file using `Remmina SNAP Build - 1.4.12 (git 0ad90e24)` to connect to a Win10 machine.

I only care about performance so I set the quality settings to poor. My own machine uses a resolution of `2560x1440 pixels`. Information about my internet connection

- Ping: 10ms
- Download: 103 Mbps
- Upload: 43 Mbps

These are my current settings I found at `~/snap/remmina/4745/.local/share/remmina`

```
[remmina]
shareparallel=0
window_width=1383
disableclipboard=0
serialpath=
disablepasswordstoring=0
disable_fastpath=0
viewmode=1
shareserial=0
password=aPasswordHere
left-handed=0
parallelname=
gateway_password=aPasswordHere
sharesmartcard=0
old-license=0
authentication level=2
ssh_tunnel_loopback=0
shareprinter=1
resolution_height=0
group=
enable-autostart=0
ssh_tunnel_enabled=0
smartcardname=
gwtransp=http
domain=theDomainHere
serialname=
ssh_tunnel_auth=0
ssh_tunnel_server=
loadbalanceinfo=
ignore-tls-errors=1
clientname=
base-cred-for-gw=0
sound=local
freerdp_log_level=INFO
resolution_mode=2
ssh_tunnel_password=
protocol=RDP
usb=
name=theNameHere
gateway_username=theUsernameHere
preferipv6=0
window_maximize=1
dvc=
relax-order-checks=0
vc=
clientbuild=
postcommand=
quality=0
username=theUsernameHere
gateway_usage=1
window_height=650
security=
resolution_width=0
ssh_tunnel_privatekey=
console=0
gateway_server=rdp.domainhere.de:3390
ssh_tunnel_passphrase=
microphone=
disableautoreconnect=0
ssh_tunnel_username=
keyboard_grab=0
glyph-cache=0
serialpermissive=0
network=none
ssh_tunnel_certfile=
execpath=
multitransport=0
multimon=0
cert_ignore=0
monitorids=
exec=
span=0
audio-output=
notes_text=
freerdp_log_filters=
parallelpath=
printer_overrides=
timeout=
serialdriver=
precommand=
server=theServerHere
useproxyenv=0
colordepth=0
gateway_domain=theDomainHere
sharefolder=
scale=0
```

Unfortunately the performance is poor. Does someone know what's missing to improve it?

Please let me know if any information is missing!

Answer (score 2):

I only ever used remmina binary from the repository and haven't had any performence issues.

Since you're using the snap package, it might be tied to this.

Maybe try using the binary from the repository and compare the performence.

```
sudo apt install remmina
```

Hope this helps.